# How do I edit a file in /proc that can be viewed with cat, but is not editable by mousepad and abiword?

Tags: cat, proc

As the question says, I need to edit my `/proc/acpi/wakeup` file, but when I open it with any text editor, it shows blank file. `cat` command, on the other hand, displays correct file contents in terminal. When I navigate to that file in file manager, it says it's size is 0 bytes. I'm using Xubuntu 15.04. I'm thoroughly confused.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`/proc` ([manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/proc.5), [kernel docs](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/proc.txt)) is a virtual filesystem (as is `/sys` - [kernel docs](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/sysfs.txt)). Files in `/proc` aren't *real* files, but ways to access information and settings from the kernel. You shouldn't use an editor to edit files in `/proc`, but write directly to these files:

```
sudo sh -c 'echo foo > /proc/some/file'
echo foo | sudo tee /proc/some/file
```

When you attempt to read or write from it, the kernel converts the actions to system calls internally and does the right thing. Some editors can still view the contents (try Vim, for example), but writing to it is a different story.

---

For a special class of files, those in `/proc/sys` ([kernel docs](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/sysctl/), [Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/sysctl)), there's another alternative. You can use the configuration files in [`/etc/sysctl.conf`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/sysctl.conf.5) and `/etc/sysctl.d/*.conf` to make permanent changes to their values. A file `/proc/sys/foo/bar` can be set using a key `foo.bar` in one of these files.

For example, `/proc/sys/vm/swappiness` can be set by adding a `/etc/sysctl.d/90-swappiness.conf` containing:

```
vm.swappiness = 10
```

And running:

```
service procps start
```

You can also make one-off changes (that will not survive the next reboot) by using the [`sysctl`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/sysctl.8) command directly:

```
sudo sysctl -w vm.swappiness=10
```

Comment: since we recently marked [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/1046737/454520) as a duplicate for this one. What do you think of adding something about `sysctl` and `/proc/sys`?