# i can not edit file even after entered root password

Tags: permissions, brightness, gedit, backlight

i want to edit actual_brightness with gedit in (/sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0) to change brightness level.
my way is pressing alt+f2 then gksudo gedit then enter the password
after editing the number and press save
its give me (you don't have the permission necessary to save the file)

note:i cannot change brightness level from settings

where is the mistake?

Comment: First of all what is you video adapter? Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'` terminal command. And what is your computer model?

Comment: possible duplicate of [cat showing file content but mousepad and abiword won't](http://askubuntu.com/questions/642817/cat-showing-file-content-but-mousepad-and-abiword-wont)

Comment: Whatever I said about `/proc` is equally applicable to `/sys`.

Answer (score 0):

run `ll /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0` and you'll probably get something like this

```
% ll /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/
total 0
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Jul  6 14:01 actual_brightness
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Jul  6 14:01 bl_power
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Jul  6 14:01 brightness
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    0 Jul  6 14:01 device -> ../../card0-eDP-1
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Jul  6 14:01 max_brightness
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root    0 Jul  6 14:01 power
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    0 Jul  6 14:01 subsystem -> ../../../../../../../class/backlight
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Jul  6 14:01 type
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Jul  6 14:01 uevent
```

actual_brightness is read-only. I'm guessing you're supposed to write to brightness, and actual_brightness will be automatically updated when/if your write to brightness causes an update.

Before you do this, though, try xbacklight.

Comment: did you try xbacklight?

Comment: you mean xbacklight file ? no i don't have it ... see the picture http://i.imgur.com/7e5NPcM.png

Comment: the program xbacklight

Comment: by mistake i delete my first replay it was (after i edit brightness file it say: could not create backup file  while saving . save any way ? when press save any way it ask me again same question and repeat it)

Comment: seriously, use xbacklight. it will probably work.

Comment: i downloaded xbacklight and nothing happened http://i.imgur.com/bLFO2mR.png

Comment: it's possible that you don't have hardware backlight support (in which case i don't think writing to brightness will work). if it doesn't, you could also try `xrandr --brightness 0.5` which will set brightness to 50% via software. xrandr is in pkg x11-xserver-utils.

Answer (score 0):

To write a number to a system file you do it like this:

```
echo "5" | sudo tee /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness
```

or

```
sudo tee /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness <<< "5"
```

But in your case it may be not `acpi_video0` but `intel_backlight`.

Depending on your laptop model and video adapter this issue can be fixed by adding kernel boot parameters.

Answer (score -1):

2 possibilities I can think of:

- Sudo ain't giving you "full" root rights. Sudo is just executing stuff with root's rights while still being you - roughly speaking.
  (It also does not require root password, but sudo password, this might even be the password of the user who is "sudo-ing")
  It might fix your problem if you try to *become* root: do "su" in the terminal and enter the roots password. You will see that your prompt will change to root@PCNAME. Then try editing the file with gedit (launch via this terminal session ofcourse) again.
- If this does not work, it's simply not a permission problem (afaik) - the file is read-only. Part of the unix-philosophy is "everything is a file". Even devices, even not really "existing" stuff.
  It does not always make sense to have something writable. Example: No matter how much permissions you have, you never will be able to really mount an iso read-writeable.
  So: Try achieving the same without writing the "file" ;-)