# Ubuntu 18 edit root files

Tags: files, root

I have to change `/proc/sys/kernel/yama/ptrace_scope` value in order to use gdb attach. Whenever I change it with `sudo nano` or `sudo gedit`, it says: no permission or gives me an error and when I restart my PC it resets back to 2.

Answer (score 3):

As it is explained in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/642823/454520), you can't open a file from `/proc` in an editor because it is virtual.

Files in `/proc/sys` can be managed using the [`sysctl`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man8/sysctl.8.html) utility.

**Temporary change**

```
sudo sysctl -w kernel.yama.ptrace_scope=0
```

**Permanent change**

Edit the `/etc/sysctl.conf` and add this line:

```
kernel.yama.ptrace_scope=0
```

As you may already know, changing this setting may have security implications (see the [documentation for yama](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/security/Yama.txt)).